# How can I use State in MaterialTable EditField Component

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am trying to use this.state inside the editComponent of material table and i cannot get it to work. Here is my code. Any ideas how i need to pass state to edit component? Please help.

```
class App extends Component(){

   this.state = {
     textValue = "Hello"
   }

  render(){

   return <MaterialTable 
   ....
   components: {{ 
       EditField: props => (<div>
           <TextField value= {this.state.textValue}           
       </div>
      )
     }}
   />
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your this.sate.textValue in a variable and pass it into EditComponent. Using this way, you can avoid binding "this" keyword is lost

```
class App extends Component(){

   this.state = {
     textValue = "Hello"
   }

  render(){

   const { textValue } = this.state;

   return <MaterialTable 
   ....
   data: 
   components: {{ 
       EditField: props => (<div>
           <TextField value= {textValue}           
       </div>
      )
     }}
   />
  } 
}
```

Comment: It dosen't work. I don't think you understood my question. EditField Component only has access to props. I am looking to pass textValue as a prop to the EditField Component.

Comment: Maybe you want to pass it in data = [] and access it using props.data ?